# How do I download attachments from unread emails in Outlook 2013?

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to download all of the attachments of the unread messages in a specific folder. As a test, I tried to loop print the subject line of each unread message, but am only getting the top email's. Please help. Also, is there a way to mark the message as read?

Thanks,

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders('The Machine').Folders('Delivered Assets').Folders('Daily')
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
attachments = message.Attachments
attachment = attachments.Item(1)
#attachment.SaveAsFile('C:\\temp\\' + attachment.FileName) #this downloads the attachment to specified path

for item in messages: 
    if item.Unread==True:
        print message.Subject #this only prints the top email's subject
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to iterate over all unread emails in the folder. To get this done you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class. You can read more about these methods and find the sample code in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

For example, in C# it will look like the code listed below:

```
string restrictCriteria = "[UnRead] = true";
StringBuilder strBuilder = null;
Outlook.Items folderItems = null;
Outlook.Items resultItems = null;
Outlook._MailItem mail = null;
int counter = default(int);
object item = null;
try
{
    strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    folderItems = folder.Items;
    resultItems = folderItems.Restrict(restrictCriteria);
    item = resultItems.GetFirst();
    while (item != null)
    {
        if (item is Outlook._MailItem)
        {
            counter++;
            mail = item as Outlook._MailItem;
            strBuilder.AppendLine("#" + counter.ToString() +
                               "\tSubject: " + mail.Subject);
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
        item = resultItems.GetNext();
    }
    if (strBuilder.Length > 0)
        Debug.WriteLine(strBuilder.ToString());
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("There is no match in the "
                         + folder.Name + " folder.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (folderItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
    if (resultItems != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(resultItems);
}
```

To save the attached file you need to use the [SaveAsFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869359(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Attachment class. The [Attachments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866435(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class returns an Attachments object that represents all the attachments for the specified item.

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I am a newb. I will try to convert this to Python and get back to you.